# Could not autowire: No 'MongoTemplate' type found in IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am a newbie at Spring Boot framework.

I am trying to develop a server which responds to clients' requests providing json files representing book models in my mongodb repository through a REST API architecture.

This is what I have:

**Book**

```
public class Book implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String author;

    public Book(String id, String name, String author) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.author = author;
    }

    // Getters and setters here
}
```

**BookController**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/books")
public class BookController {
    private final BookService bookService;

    @Autowired
    public BookController(BookService bookService) {
        this.bookService = bookService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<Book> getBooks() {
        return bookService.getBooks();
    }

    @GetMapping(params = "author")
    public List<Book> getBooksByAuthor(@RequestParam String author) {
        return bookService.getBooksByAuthor(author);
    }
}
```

**BookService**

```
@Service
public class BookService {
    @Autowired // warning: field injection is not recommended
    private BookRepository bookRepository; 
    @Autowired // warning: field injection is not recommended
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate; // warning: could not autowire. No 'MongoTemplate' type found

    public List<Book> getBooks() {
        return bookRepository.findAll();
    }

    public List<Book> getBooksByAuthor(String author) {
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("author").is(author));
        return mongoTemplate.find(query, Book.class);
    }
}
```

**BookRepository**

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends MongoRepository<Book, String> {
}
```

Even though `localhost:8080/api/v1/books?author=SOMETHING` works properly, IntelliJ warns me that `@Autowired private BookRepository bookRepository;`

> field injection is not recommended

and `@Autowired private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;`

> field injection is not recommended

> could not autowire. No 'MongoTemplate' type found

I have these questions:

- Is the structure of this server application correct? I mean, the interaction between each components (controller, service and repository)
- How can I overcome these two warnings in `BookService`?
- Is there any change you would apply to my code? For example naming conventions, autowiring and so on? (Some advices, I mean). For example I would move

  Query query = new Query();
  query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("author").is(author));
  return mongoTemplate.find(query, Book.class);

statements as a `BookRepository`

Comment: You can try `MongoOperations` (the interface `MongoTemplate` implements).

Comment: @prasad_ It would still give me "Could not autowire. No 'MongoOperation' type found".

Comment: Intellij doesn't see the autoconfig of Spring and thus not those beans. So intellij is wrong your application will work fine. Regarding field injection, just remove `@Autowired`, make the fields final and create a proper constructor. Additionally the `@Repository` on your `BookRepository` is useless remove it.

Comment: @M.Deinum Even though i do this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate in the constructor, it gives me the same warning (could not autowire)

Comment: Correct, because as I mentioned before, Intellij doesn't know about the Spring Boot autoconfiugration and as such thinks that the bean won't be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filed injection is not recommended, to avoid this kind of warnings you should give priority to constructor injections, which allows you to build immutable components.

Like this:

```
@Service
public class BookService {
    private final BookRepository bookRepository;

    public BookService(BookRepository bookRepository) {
        this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
    }

    public List<Book> getBooks() {
        return bookRepository.findAll();
    }

    public List<Book> getBooksByAuthor(String author) {
        return bookRepository.findAllByAuthor(author);
    }
}
```

About the MongoTemplate - why don't you create a method 'findAllByAuthor' inside your  BookRepository interface instead of using MongoTemplate? This will make your code more general and will incapsulate query logic into repository class where it should be incapsulated.

Comment: I have tried to add the signature findAllByAuthor(String author); in my BookRepository and the application is working, returning the books written by that author. But how is it possible if this method has not been concretely implemented?

Comment: Repository code generated by spring data under the hood according to https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries